# How to find the location of maximum and minimum value of a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, max

I don't know if i am being clear with this but I already have the minimum and the maximum printing out right, but I can't seem to figure out how to say the exact row and column they are in. 
this is what i have so far;

```
double max = m[0][0];
       double min =  m[0][0];
    System.out.println("The matrix is : ");

        for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++ )
            {
                System.out.printf("   " + "%6.1f " , m[i][j]);
                if (m[i][j] > max)
                    max = m [i][j];     

                else if
                (m[i][j] < min)
                    min = m [i][j];
```

how can I make a statement saying their locations? for example : ("Maximun number is in row 1 , column 2") something like that...
I'd really appreciate any help

Comment: When you do `max = m[i][j]`, also store the location. So at the top, have `double max = m[0][0]; int x = 0; int y = 0;` where `x` and `y` are coordinates. So under `max = m[i][j]`, you write `x = i; y = j;`.

Comment: Generally speaking, the best way to store max and min, is to keep tabs of the 'running' max and min as you are entering values into the arrays, if you have the option to. You didn't show how you are entering values into the array, so I don't know if you are controlling that or if it's an external force. If you are entering the values into the arrays, then trying to search for it after the fact is unnecessary and wasteful considering you already have the ability to know that information before hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the below modification. I added variables to track the indices of the min and max. At the end of your loop you can simply print out `maxIndex1`, `maxIndex2`, `minIndex1`, and `minIndex2`.

```
double max = m[0][0];
double min =  m[0][0];

//declare variables to track the indices of the min and max
int maxIndex1 = -1;
int maxIndex2 = -1;
int minIndex1 = -1;
int minIndex2 = -1;

System.out.println("The matrix is : ");
for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++ )
    {
        System.out.printf("   " + "%6.1f " , m[i][j]);
        if (m[i][j] > max)
        {
            max = m [i][j]; 
            //record the indices of the new max
            maxIndex1 = i;
            maxIndex2 = j;  
        }  
        else if (m[i][j] < min)
        {
            min = m [i][j];
            //record the indices of the new min
            minIndex1 = i;
            minIndex2 = j;
        }
```

Note that if you have two values that are equal and are tied for the max value in the array, this will only record one of the two. If you wanted to record the positions of all ties for min / max, you could change this to save a list of co-ordinates instead of a single co-ordinate.

Comment: Worth noting that this works only if the max and min values are unique in the matrix, since you're storing only one location.

Comment: You could drop the `else` from `else if` in case you have a sorted array.

Comment: @Gendarme I think this example will work for what OP wants, but it is definitely worth noting. I edited my post to include that.

Comment: To the OP: consider doing the first dimension of the array across multiple parallel threads to decrease the time it takes to locate a min and max value

Comment: @searchengine27 not a bad idea if the arrays in question are very large. If they are normal size, this optimization is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

That is easy! Just declare 2 more variables to store your x and y coordinates. And update them inside both if and else (don't forget to add curly braces to your if and else clause!) and you have them!

Comment: Curly braces aren't necessary in this case.

Comment: The literal grammar per the Java spec for an if statement is `if ParExpression Statement [else Statement]` where `Statement` is a block or a single line statement. I agree, curly braces are unneccessary and purely optional and personal preference.

Comment: So, you are saying this is fine?! if (m[i][j] > max) max = m [i][j]; maxIndex1=i; maxIndex2=j;